# Delphi LogN and Power - SuperEllipse functions - algorithm

Tags: delphi, math, elliptic-curve

How can I isolate the 'slope' parameter in the super ellipse function given by:

MyY := (1.0- (power(1.0-power(x, 2.0/Slope), Slope*0.5)))

when I know 'x' and 'MyY' ?
(the function is always used in the range of 0 to 1).

Answer (score 1):

No easy way. This equation cannot be solved algebraically. You need to use numerical methods to find the solution (e.g. [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)).

Answer (score 0):

I don't need to solve it, to be more precise when i call the function 'MyY :=...', 'x' and 'Slope' are known.

I just need to express it in function of Slope. Instead of MyY := ... I need Slope := ... and I know 'x' and 'MyY'. I just need to express the transfert function in another way, the problem is when using logN I get someting like: (x is always 0.5 , y varies but is know)

Slope/2 = LogN(power(1.0-power(0.5, 2.0/Slope)) (whatever the '1 -', this is not what's stucking me)

from this I cannot move or clear '2.0/slope' from the right part of the equation.
On the software way it's used to keep a correlation between a control point and the cursor mouse.

It's just like this: (by analogy)
 MyY := power(x,slope)  // MyY := (1.0- (power(1.0-power(x, 2.0/Slope), Slope*0.5))) 
slope := Logn(x,MyY)    // slope := ?

I just need to express it in another way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please reserve this "answer" section for responses that actually *answer* the question. Answers that don't really answer the question are liable to get voted down, costing you reputation points. To respond to somebody else's answer, please use the "add comment" link below each answer. If your response is meant to clarify the question, then just edit the question itself. Also, please remember to use the same account each time you return. Use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page to ask a site admin to merge your two accounts.